# OAuth2 endpoints for EWS access to office365

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

I have an app that uses Basic Authentication to access office365 via EWS, is there any documentation on how to do OAuth2 with EWS?

What endpoints do I authenticate with?

I have searched google but cant seem to find information on using OAuth2 with EWS.

Answer (score 1):

You use the Standard Azure oAuth tokens and endpoints (using the ADAL library if you wish which makes things easy) there is a step by step document for doing this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903761(v=exchg.150).aspx . The only point to remember is that EWS only has one authentication scope which is Full Mailbox Access. All the other Mail,Calendar,Contacts scopes are for the new REST API only.

Comment: So are you saying that I cannot access calendar readwrite scope thru AAD?  I need to do calendar readwrites using EWS but my customers are complaining about using basic authenication.

Comment: Yes with EWS you need to use the Full Mailbox Access scope the other scope are for the REST API's only.

Comment: Unfortunately the page you recommended has several links that are broken and take you to a 404 file not found page.  Seems this information is no longer bring maintained.

Comment: Its pretty simple through you just register your app in Azure give it Full Mailbox Access and then its like any other oAuth app you get the access token set the Bearer header and that's it.

Comment: I know it's easy but I need to know the endpoints to call to get a token, Microsoft graph endpoints don't work.  I cant use the AAD authentication library since  I'm writing in Python on an embedded linux processor.  .NET wont help me either.

Comment: The endpoints you use for EWS are the same as the Graph eg https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize and https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token there are only two possible endpoints you could use with EWS don't use v2 endpoints and configure your application via the Azure Management portal eg https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/RegisterAnAppInAzure.md . If you get an error you should always post the error and code rather then saying something doesn't work.